# android-location shows in toast but not in textview

Tags: android, location

My android application shows last/new location in `TOAST` in android. I have added `TextView` to show location in `TextView` but the app does not show in `TextView`. I also properly initialize `findViewById` in `Activity`.

code is here:

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView SMS_textview;
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1;
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    SMS_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sms_text);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format( "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        SMS_textview.setText(message);
        Toast.makeText(home.this, message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Location Details",message);
    }
}
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(home.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(home.this, "Provider status changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(home.this,"Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(home.this,"Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not set text in textview inside onLocationChanged method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String message = String.format(
            "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
    );
      // set location in textview
     SMS_textview.setText(message);
    Toast.makeText(home.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set message text into `TextView` inside `onLocationChanged` as below :

If `LocationManager` don't know your last location then your `TextView` not able to show location so you have to set location message text inside `onLocationChanged` to show update location into `TextView`.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  String message = String.format("New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
  Toast.makeText(home.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  SMS_textview.setText(message);
}
```